# Making rest api calls from iOS app one after another

Tags: ios

Trying to make rest api calls from an iOS app using this method http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-ios/
Need to make 3 api calls one after another and need to utilize part of the json result in the subsequent api call. How should I proceed?
iOS app is been developed using Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a background thread like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        <#code#>
    });
```

And execute your API calls synchronously within it.  It might look something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        id dataOne = [self apiCallOne];
        id dataTwo = [self apiCallTwoWithDataOne:dataOne];
        id dataThree = [self apiCallThreeWithDataTwo:dataTwo];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Completion with data: %@", dataThree);
            });
    });
```

Make sure to use `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: ...];` as opposed to `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: ...];`

Comment: Please update your answer for NSURLSession as NSURLConnection has been deprecated....